# Weibel 1.5.8: Well-definedness of long exact sequence containing homology of $f$

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm currently reading Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra* and I am a little stuck in section 1.5.8. In the sections before it is proven that the homology of each map $f : B_. \to C_.$ occurs in some long exact sequence, using mapping cones and cylinders. Namely, the homology of $f$ occurs in the long exact sequences obtained from the complexes
$$0 \to B_. \to \text{cyl}(f) \to \text{cone}(f) \to 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 \to C_. \to \text{cone}(f) \to B[-1] \to 0.$$

He next claims that "the long exact sequence is well defined". I'm not completely sure what is meant by this formulation. I suppose, it could mean that up to some nice equivalence relation (isomorphism maybe?), there is only one such long exact sequence. The only thing proven in this section, however, is that for a monomorphism $f$ the long exact sequence obtained from $\text{cone}(f)$ and $\text{cyl}(f)$ is isomorphic to the one obtained from the short exact sequence
$$0 \to B_. \stackrel{f}{\to} C_. \stackrel{g}{\to} D_. \to 0.$$
Here $g$ is the cokernel of $f$. An exercise provides the dual statement for epimorphisms. I don't really see a connection to the statement we want to prove here.

My questions are:

1. Is my interpretation of the phrase "the long exact sequence is well defined" correct?
2. How do the results about monos and epis prove this?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the main point of that section is the following:

So up to this point, we know how to fit the homology of $f : B_{\bullet} \to C_\bullet $ into some long exact sequence by either using one of the short exact sequences:

$$ 0 \to B_\bullet \to \text{cyl}(f) \to \text{cone}(f) \to 0 \ (*) \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 \to C_\bullet \to \text{cone}(f) \to B[-1] \to 0 \ (**).$$

Now we want to show that in fact, this process of fitting the homology is **"unique"** (up to quasi-isomorphism), meaning, if we have any other $D_\bullet$ such that $0 \to B_\bullet \stackrel{f}{\to} C_\bullet \stackrel{g}{\to} D_\bullet \to 0$ is exact, then the long exact sequence that it produces must be the "**same"** (up to quasi-isomorphism) as the long exact sequence that we get from applying $(*)$ or $(**)$.

The proof was shown in the book or explained more explicitly by butter-imbiber above (but I think you already knew). I'm not sure I understand the part when you mentioned about monos and epis $f$ though, since it was proved for *any* $f$ in the textbook the result that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Q1 is yes. I'll expand on an answer to Q2 below.

(I don't know how to get tikzcd diagrams onto StackExchange and I don't have enough reputation to include images. You'll have to follow these links to see what I mean. I also don't have enough reputation to comment. My apologies.)

In 1.5.8, Weibel draws [a diagram with exact rows in the category of complexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFfK2.png). Let's call this diagram (1).

The three rows in (1) have been seen before in 1.5.2 and on p22. The vertical morphisms are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\varphi$. The morphism $\varphi$ is new, but $\alpha$ was seen in Lemma 1.5.6 (where, confusingly, the Lemma uses $C$ while (1) uses $B$) and $\beta$ was seen just afterwards in Exercise 1.5.4. We know both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are quasiisomorphisms. We can deduce that $\varphi$ is a quasiisomorphism too, by the argument Weibel gives after (1) on p23.

Applying homology to each of the three rows in this diagram gives us the rows [in the following diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOYVB.png), all of which are long exact sequences. We'll call this second diagram (2). The vertical maps in diagram (2) are either identities (which are isomorphisms) or the morphisms $H_n(\alpha),H_n(\beta),H_n(\varphi)$ (which are isomorphisms).

All the vertical morphisms in (2) are therefore all isomorphisms. This proves that all three long exact sequences are isomorphic.

---

EDITS: copy editing

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that *those three* long exact sequences are isomorphic. My question, however, is a slightly different one. Are *all* long exact sequences involving $\mathrm{H}(f)$ isomorphic?